# grouped category chart d3 4 levels of groups

Tags: d3.js

Hi I am new to D3 and svg.I need to create grouped category bar and grouped category line both. Literally i don't know how to take domain and range and scale for this. Finally I found a category grouped bar chart with d3 in this link
[grouped category bar chart with different groups in d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812922/grouped-category-bar-chart-with-different-groups-in-d3)

But the above link has only two levels but my requirement needs multiple nested values, I required graph structure like this  [my data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icl4h.png) and this is my [sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNK4d.jpg).
I tried a three level category grouped bar chart based on the above link but I did not get proper chart. And I need that four level category grouped chart as bar and line chart.

code i tried

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 360 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var color = {
  Mechanical: '#4A7B9D',
  Electrical: '#54577C',
  Hydraulic: '#ED6A5A'
};
var barPadding = 5;
var data = [{
  key: 'Mechanical',
  values: [{
    key: 'Gear',
    values: [{
        key: 'Gear',
        value: 11
     },{
     key: 'Gear1',
        value: 11
     },{
     key: 'Gear2',
        value: 11
     }]
     }, {
    key: 'Bearing',
     values:[{
        key: 'Gears',
        value: 11
     },{
     key: 'Gear3',
     value: 11
     },{
         key: 'Gear12',
        value: 11
     }]
  }
  
   
  ]
}, {
  key: 'Electrical',
  values: [{
    key: 'Switch',
    values: [{
    key: 'Switch',
    values: 19
  }, {
    key: 'Motor',
    value: 12
  }, {
    key: 'Cord',
    value: 11
  }]
  
}]
}]
;
var rangeBands = [];
var cummulative = 0;
var cummutativeForData = 0;
data.forEach(function(val, i) {
  val.cummulative = cummulative;
  
  val.values.forEach(function(values) {
    values.cummutativeForData = cummutativeForData;
    cummutativeForData += values.values.length;
    values.parentKey = val.key;
    values.values.forEach(function(val){
    rangeBands.push(i);
  })
  })
  cummulative += val.values.length + cummutativeForData;
});

var x_category = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width]);


var x_defect = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(rangeBands).rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var x_category_domain = x_defect.rangeBand() * rangeBands.length;
x_category.domain([0, x_category_domain]);


var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(cat) {
  return d3.max(cat.values, function(def) {
     return d3.max(def.values, function(def1) {
    return def1.value;
})
  });
})]);

var category_axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x_category)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .style('background-color', 'EFEFEF')
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Value");

var category_g = svg.selectAll(".category")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category category-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x_category((d.cummulative * x_defect.rangeBand())) + ",0)";
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color[d.key];
  });

var category_label = category_g.selectAll(".category-label")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category-label category-label-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (x_category((d.values.length * d.values.length *x_defect.rangeBand()) / 2)) + "," + (height + 60) + ")";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

var defect_g = category_g.selectAll(".defect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'defect defect-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x_category((d.values.length * x_defect.rangeBand()*i)) + ",0)";
  });


var defect1_g = defect_g.selectAll(".defect1")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'defect defect-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x_category(( x_defect.rangeBand()*i)) + ",0)";
  });

var defect_label = defect_g.selectAll(".defect-label")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'defect-label defect-label-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return x_category(  2 + 12);
  })
  .attr('y', height + 30)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');


var defect_label1 = defect1_g.selectAll(".defect-label1")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'defect-label defect-label-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return x_category( 2 );
  })
  .attr('y', height + 20)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');



var rects = defect1_g.selectAll('.rect')
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("width", x_category(x_defect.rangeBand()))
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x_category(barPadding);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "tried 3 level category grouped bar chart based on above link.but i did not get proper graph" --> Can you show your code and explain how the result is different from your expectations?

Comment: @bwyn i added code i tried