# How to get tool tip for grouped category bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to JavaScript and d3.

My requirement is to draw grouped category bar chart. Initially, I didn't know how to take domain and range for grouped bar chart. However with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812922/grouped-category-bar-chart-with-different-groups-in-d3/37823055#37823055), I am able to draw grouped category bar chart of different levels.

My challenge now is to display tool tip when mouse hovers over the bars. Can anyone please suggest how to display the tool tip for the above bar chart?

I also tried following [this guide](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579), but have had no success.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try foxToolTip.js
https://github.com/MichaelRFox/foxToolTip.js

Read the README.md and check out the bl.ock in the d3.js section.