# X axis label not displayed in bar chart with scroll and zoom feature - d3js, Brushing

Tags: d3.js

My requirement is to generate  Bar Chart With Panning And Zooming Via Brushing to overcome the x axis label overlapping id data is more.I implemented bar chart panning and zooming via brushing based on below link example
http://bl.ocks.org/MartynJones87/7db0d637e178e7204c0a
I am able to get panning and zooming but x axis labels are not displayed on axis.I don't know where i did mistake.

here is the [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/BPLZkBMlcUCS7UF90aXM?p=preview) for code.

On data load the core code called is:

```
var xBrush = d3.svg.brush().x(min_x).on("brush", xBrushed);

// Called to re-draw the bars on the main chart when the brush on the x axis
        // has been altered.
        function xBrushed() {
            var originalRange = main_xZoom.range();
            main_xZoom.domain(xBrush.empty() ? originalRange : xBrush.extent());
            x.rangeRoundBands([main_xZoom(originalRange[0]), main_xZoom(originalRange[1])], .2);

            //main_x1.rangeRoundBands([0, x.rangeBand()], 0);

            main.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .attr("width", function (d) {

                    return x.rangeBand();
                })
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                                    //   alert("d is"+JSON.stringify(d));

                    return x(d.letter);

                });

            main.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis).selectAll(".tick text").call(wrap, x.rangeBand());
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find two issues in your code.

1. The `clipPath` rectangle used in svg `defs` is also getting updated within `xBrushed` function. The problem is with the selector you used.

   You should have used

   ```
   main.selectAll(".rect") //which selects all elements with class rect in main selection.
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   main.selectAll("rect") //which selects all rect elements in main selection which includes clipPath rect also.
   ```

   within the `xBrushed` function.
2. You will need to apply the `clip-path` attribute to the group element which holds the rectangle bar elements.

**Working code snippet:**

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 860 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var min_margin = {
    top: height,
    right: margin.right + 10,
    bottom: margin.bottom,
    left: margin.left + 10
  },
  min_height = 10,
  min_width = 860 - min_margin.left - min_margin.right;




var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

var min_x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);


var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var min_xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(min_x)
  .orient("bottom");



var main_xZoom = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, width]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var main = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

main.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height + min_height + margin.bottom);


var mini_x_append = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + min_margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height) + ")")
  .attr("width", min_width);


var data = [{
  "letter": "A~q112",
  "frequency": 0.08167
}, {
  "letter": "B~12",
  "frequency": 0.01492
}, {
  "letter": "C~c",
  "frequency": 0.02782
}, {
  "letter": "D~1a",
  "frequency": 0.04253
}, {
  "letter": "E~d",
  "frequency": 0.12702
}, {
  "letter": "F~x",
  "frequency": 0.02288
}, {
  "letter": "G~v",
  "frequency": 0.02015
}, {
  "letter": "H~xs",
  "frequency": 0.06094
}, {
  "letter": "I~za",
  "frequency": 0.06966
}, {
  "letter": "J~mj",
  "frequency": 0.00153
}, {
  "letter": "K~th",
  "frequency": 0.00772
}, {
  "letter": "L~ws",
  "frequency": 0.04025
}, {
  "letter": "M~qjl",
  "frequency": 0.02406
}, {
  "letter": "N~i",
  "frequency": 0.06749
}, {
  "letter": "O~p",
  "frequency": 0.07507
}, {
  "letter": "P~zs",
  "frequency": 0.01929
}, {
  "letter": "Q~rip",
  "frequency": 0.00095
}, {
  "letter": "R~hi",
  "frequency": 0.05987
}, {
  "letter": "S~eop",
  "frequency": 0.06327
}, {
  "letter": "T~tl",
  "frequency": 0.09056
}, {
  "letter": "U~se",
  "frequency": 0.02758
}, {
  "letter": "V~wh",
  "frequency": 0.00978
}, {
  "letter": "W~jl",
  "frequency": 0.0236
}, {
  "letter": "X~y",
  "frequency": 0.0015
}, {
  "letter": "Y~ty",
  "frequency": 0.01974
}, {
  "letter": "Z~o",
  "frequency": 0.00074
}, {
  "letter": "A~q12",
  "frequency": 0.08167
}, {
  "letter": "B~122",
  "frequency": 0.01492
}, {
  "letter": "C~c2",
  "frequency": 0.02782
}, {
  "letter": "D~1a2",
  "frequency": 0.04253
}, {
  "letter": "E~d2",
  "frequency": 0.12702
}, {
  "letter": "F~x2",
  "frequency": 0.02288
}, {
  "letter": "G~v2",
  "frequency": 0.02015
}, {
  "letter": "H~xs2",
  "frequency": 0.06094
}, {
  "letter": "I~za2",
  "frequency": 0.06966
}, {
  "letter": "J~mj2",
  "frequency": 0.00153
}, {
  "letter": "K~th2",
  "frequency": 0.00772
}, {
  "letter": "L~ws2",
  "frequency": 0.04025
}, {
  "letter": "M~qjl2",
  "frequency": 0.02406
}, {
  "letter": "N~i2",
  "frequency": 0.06749
}, {
  "letter": "O~p2",
  "frequency": 0.07507
}, {
  "letter": "P~zs2",
  "frequency": 0.01929
}, {
  "letter": "Q~rip2",
  "frequency": 0.00095
}, {
  "letter": "R~hi2",
  "frequency": 0.05987
}, {
  "letter": "S~eo2p",
  "frequency": 0.06327
}, {
  "letter": "T~tl2",
  "frequency": 0.09056
}, {
  "letter": "U~se2",
  "frequency": 0.02758
}, {
  "letter": "V~wh2",
  "frequency": 0.00978
}, {
  "letter": "W~jl2",
  "frequency": 0.0236
}, {
  "letter": "X~y2",
  "frequency": 0.0015
}, {
  "letter": "Y~ty2",
  "frequency": 0.01974
}, {
  "letter": "Z~o2",
  "frequency": 0.00074
}];





x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
min_x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency;
})]);


var xBrush = d3.svg.brush().x(min_x).on("brush", xBrushed);

// Add the x axis


main.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + min_height) + ")")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());


var x_arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(min_height / 2)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(function(d, i) {
    return i ? -Math.PI : Math.PI;
  });

var brush_x_grab = mini_x_append.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x brush")
  .call(xBrush);

brush_x_grab.selectAll(".resize").append("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + min_height / 2 + ")")
  .attr("d", x_arc);

brush_x_grab.selectAll("rect").attr("height", min_height);





main.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);


var bar = main.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .selectAll(".rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  });



// Called to re-draw the bars on the main chart when the brush on the x axis
// has been altered.
function xBrushed() {
  var originalRange = main_xZoom.range();
  
  main_xZoom.domain(xBrush.empty() ? originalRange : xBrush.extent());
  
  x.rangeRoundBands([main_xZoom(originalRange[0]), main_xZoom(originalRange[1])], .2);

 // min_x.rangeRoundBands([0, x.rangeBand()], 0);

  main.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(data)
    .attr("width", function(d) {

      return x.rangeBand();
    })
  
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      //   alert("d is"+JSON.stringify(d));


      return x(d.letter);

    
    }); 

  main.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis).selectAll(".tick text").call(wrap, x.rangeBand());
};

// This comes from the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
// for wrapping long axis tick labels
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      //   console.log("wrap is"+JSON.stringify(word));
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
};



// Set the initial brush selections.
// svg.select(".x.brush").call(xBrush.extent(main_xZoom.domain()));
svg.select(".x.brush").call(xBrush.extent([0, 110]));
//svg.select(".y.brush").call(yBrush.extent(mini_y0.domain()));

// Forces a refresh of the brushes and main chart based
// on the selected extents.
xBrushed();
//yBrushed();


function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

```css
g.axis path,
g.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
g.brush rect.extent {
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
}
.resize path {
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
}
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

I found it is more easy to implement this functionality by converting the json data you have to the same format used at this [link](http://bl.ocks.org/MartynJones87/7db0d637e178e7204c0a).

```js
var nestedData;

var main_margin = {
    top: 25,
    right: 80,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 70
  },

  width = 900 - main_margin.left - main_margin.right,
  mini_x_height = 10;
main_height = 525 - main_margin.top - main_margin.bottom,

  mini_x_margin = {
    top: main_height,
    right: main_margin.right + 10,
    bottom: main_margin.bottom,
    left: main_margin.left + 10
  },

  mini_x_width = 900 - mini_x_margin.left - mini_x_margin.right,

  mini_y_margin = {
    top: main_margin.top + 10,
    right: 0,
    bottom: main_margin.bottom + 10,
    left: 0
  },
  mini_y_width = 10,
  mini_y_height = 525 - mini_y_margin.top - mini_y_margin.bottom;


var color = d3.scale.category10();

// x0 is the groups scale on the x axis.
var main_x0 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.2);
var mini_x0 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.2);

var main_xZoom = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, width]);

// x1 is the series scale on the x axis.
var main_x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();
var mini_x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

// y is the value scale on the y axis.
var main_y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([main_height, 0]);

var mini_y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([mini_y_height, 0]);

var main_xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(main_x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var mini_xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(mini_x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var main_yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(main_y0)
  .orient("left");

var mini_yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(mini_y0)
  .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + main_margin.left + main_margin.right)
  .attr("height", main_height + main_margin.top + main_margin.bottom);

var main = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + main_margin.left + "," + main_margin.top + ")");

main.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", main_height + mini_x_height + main_margin.bottom);

var mini_x = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + mini_x_margin.left + "," + (main_margin.top + main_height) + ")")
  .attr("width", mini_x_width);

var mini_y = svg.append("g")
  .attr("width", mini_y_width)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (main_margin.left - mini_y_width) + ", " + mini_y_margin.top + ")")
  .attr("height", mini_y_height);

var data = [{
  key: 'Mechanical',
  values: [{
    key: 'Gear',
    value: 11
}, {
    key: 'Bearing',
    value: 8
  }, {
    key: 'Motor',
    value: 3
  }, {
    key: 'Bearing',
    value: 8
  }, {
    key: 'Motor',
    value: 3
  }, {
    key: 'Bearing',
    value: 8
  }, {
    key: 'Motor',
    value: 3
  }]
}, {
  key: 'Electrical',
  values: [{
    key: 'Switch',
    value: 19
  }, {
    key: 'Plug',
    value: 12
  }, {
    key: 'Cord',
    value: 11
  }, {
    key: 'Fuse',
    value: 3
  }, {
    key: 'Bulb',
    value: 2
  }]
}, {
  key: 'Hydraulic',
  values: [{
    key: 'Pump',
    value: 4
  }, {
    key: 'Leak',
    value: 3
  }, {
    key: 'Seals',
    value: 1
  },{
    key: 'Switch',
    value: 19
  }, {
    key: 'Plug',
    value: 12
  }, {
    key: 'Cord',
    value: 11
  }, {
    key: 'Fuse',
    value: 3
  }, {
    key: 'Bulb',
    value: 2
  }]
}];


var res = [];

data.forEach(function(d){ 
  res.push(d.values.map(function(o){
    o.item=o.key; 
    o.subject = d.key; return o; }));
});

data = [].concat.apply([], res);
res.sort(function(a,b){ return a.subject<b.subject });

//console.log(data);

  var seriesValues = d3.set(data.map(function(x) {
    return x.item;
  })).values().sort(d3.ascending);

  nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.subject;
    })
    .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
    .sortValues(function(a, b) {
      return a.item - b.item;
    })
    .entries(data);

  var groupValues = d3.set(data.map(function(x) {
    return x.subject;
  })).values();

  // Define the axis domains
  main_x0.domain(groupValues);
  mini_x0.domain(groupValues);

  main_x1.domain(seriesValues).rangeRoundBands([0, main_x0.rangeBand()], 0);
  mini_x1.domain(seriesValues).rangeRoundBands([0, main_x0.rangeBand()], 0);

  main_y0.domain([0, d3.max(nestedData, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d.values, function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
  })]);
  mini_y0.domain(main_y0.domain());

  var xBrush = d3.svg.brush().x(mini_x0).on("brush", xBrushed);
  var yBrush = d3.svg.brush().y(mini_y0).on("brush", yBrushed);

  // Add the x axis
  main.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (main_height + mini_x_height) + ")")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .call(main_xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
    .call(wrap, main_x0.rangeBand());

  // Add the y axis
  main.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-mini_y_width) + ", 0)")
    .call(main_yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90), translate(" + -(main_height / 2) + ", " + -(mini_y_width + main_margin.left - 20) + ")")
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("value");

  var x_arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(mini_x_height / 2)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d, i) {
      return i ? -Math.PI : Math.PI;
    });

  var brush_x_grab = mini_x.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(xBrush);

  brush_x_grab.selectAll(".resize").append("path")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + mini_x_height / 2 + ")")
    .attr("d", x_arc);

  brush_x_grab.selectAll("rect").attr("height", mini_x_height);

  var y_arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(mini_y_width / 2)
    .startAngle(-(Math.PI / 2))
    .endAngle(function(d, i) {
      return i ? -((3 * Math.PI) / 2) : ((Math.PI) / 2);
    });

  var brush_y_grab = mini_y.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y brush")
    .call(yBrush);

  brush_y_grab.selectAll(".resize").append("path")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (mini_y_width / 2) + ", 0)")
    .attr("d", y_arc);

  brush_y_grab.selectAll("rect").attr("width", mini_y_width);

  // Create the main bars
  var bar = main.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(nestedData)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.key + "-group bar";
    });

  bar.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.item;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + main_x0(d.subject) + ",0)";
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return main_x1.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return main_x1(d.item);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return main_y0(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return main_height - main_y0(d.value);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.item);
    });


  // Draws the series items onto a legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(seriesValues.slice())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(50," + (main_margin.top + (i * 20)) + ")";
    });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });

  // Called to re-draw the bars on the main chart when the brush on the x axis
  // has been altered.
  function xBrushed() {
    var originalRange = main_xZoom.range();
    main_xZoom.domain(xBrush.empty() ? originalRange : xBrush.extent());
    main_x0.rangeRoundBands([main_xZoom(originalRange[0]), main_xZoom(originalRange[1])], .1);

    main_x1.rangeRoundBands([0, main_x0.rangeBand()], 0);

    bar.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + main_x0(d.subject) + ",0)";
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return main_x1.rangeBand();
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return main_x1(d.item);
      });

    main.select("g.x.axis").call(main_xAxis).selectAll(".tick text").call(wrap, main_x0.rangeBand());
  };

  // Called to re-draw the bars on the main chart when the
  // brush on the y axis has been altered.
  function yBrushed() {
    main_y0.domain(yBrush.empty() ? mini_y0.domain() : yBrush.extent());

    bar.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return main_y0(d.value);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return main_height - main_y0(d.value);
      });

    main.select("g.y.axis").call(main_yAxis);
  };

  // This comes from the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
  // for wrapping long axis tick labels
  function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
      var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
      while (word = words.pop()) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          line = [word];
          tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
        }
      }
    });
  };

  // Set the initial brush selections.
  // svg.select(".x.brush").call(xBrush.extent(main_xZoom.domain()));
  svg.select(".x.brush").call(xBrush.extent([0, 610]));
  svg.select(".y.brush").call(yBrush.extent(mini_y0.domain()));

  // Forces a refresh of the brushes and main chart based
  // on the selected extents.
  xBrushed();
  yBrushed();

//});
```

```css
g.axis path,
g.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
g.brush rect.extent {
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
}
.resize path {
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your code helps me a lot.How can i implement this functionality for grouped category bar chart like below link one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812922/grouped-category-bar-chart-with-different-groups-in-d3/37823055#37823055.

Comment: Thank you,I tried based on link you mentioned above.But i got stuck middle.Here the plunker link for my code i tried https://plnkr.co/edit/JaeWfMK1j80v3Dbsro7C?p=preview

Comment: could you please look into the above plunker link.I got stuck their.

Comment: I found a solution for this. Can  you add this as a new question? So that I can add a new code snippet and details over there.

Comment: I have added the solution. If you have any doubts, please add it as a new question

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gilsha ,But the graph structure you have taken is different from graph structure i need.Graph structure i need is exactly  as i mention in above plunker.I added it as new question,link for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324551/grouped-category-brush-functionality-on-x-axis