# D3 Group label for xAxis ticks

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

I have a similar dataset:

```
[
  {
    date: '2019-01-01',
    value: 100,
    group: 1
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-02',
    value: 200,
    group: 1
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-03',
    value: 200,
    group: 2
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-04',
    value: 200,
    group: 3
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-05',
    value: 100,
    group: 3
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-06',
    value: 250,
    group: 3
  }
]
```

I've create a linear chart with yAxis - `value`, and xAxis - `date`.

How can I implement additional label for xAxis by `group` field value, like I show on the pic?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using `scaleTime` to create this you need to add time in your date, like `scaleLinear` and `scaleBand`, `scaleTime` need exactly value to pin the correct coordinate, but some people forgot date requires time too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <svg id="test" width="500" height="400"></svg>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  var data = [
  {
    date: '2019-01-01',
    value: 100,
    group: 1
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-02',
    value: 200,
    group: 1
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-03',
    value: 200,
    group: 2
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-04',
    value: 200,
    group: 3
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-05',
    value: 100,
    group: 3
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-06',
    value: 250,
    group: 3
  }
]

  // first, group the data
var groupedData = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.group; })
        .rollup(function(v) { return {
    count: v.length,
    lastDate: v[v.length-1].date + ' 12:00:00'
  }; })
    .entries(data)

//console.log(groupedData)
// then, get cumulative length of each group
var groupedData = groupedData.map((d, i) => {
        const prev = groupedData[(i - 1)]
        const cumsum = prev ? d.value.count + prev.cumsum : d.value.count
        d.cumsum = cumsum
        return d
      })



const svg = d3.select('svg')
var width = 500
var xscaleTime = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date('2019-01-01'), new Date('2019-01-06')])
    .range([0,500]).nice()



var bandwidth = (xscaleTime(new Date(groupedData[1].value.lastDate))
                 - xscaleTime(new Date(groupedData[0].value.lastDate)))
var padding = 20
const b = svg.append("g")
const t = b.append("g").call( d3.axisBottom().scale(xscaleTime))
const g = b.append("g")
    .attr("class", "group-labels")
    .attr("y", 30) //adjust this so that the group labels are below your labels

g.selectAll(".group-label")
    .data(groupedData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "group-label")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
      return xscaleTime(new Date (d.value.lastDate)) - bandwidth *((d.value.count-1)/2)
    })
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d,i){ 
      return 'is Group ' + d.key
    })
  
</script>
```

according to @Cathy answer, ( please read the answer she points you to good example ) i edit some for you, you can make like the example she provide by editing the data (get last date and first date of the group) and play with [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis)

Answer (score 3):

This question might help you: [grouped category bar chart with different groups in d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812922/grouped-category-bar-chart-with-different-groups-in-d3)

But if you only need to show labels and not color by each group, really all you need to do is count the number of values in each group:

```
// first, group the data
var groupedData = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.group; })
        .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
        .entries(data)

// then, get cumulative length of each group
var groupedData = groupedData.map((d, i) => {
        const prev = nestedData[(i - 1)]
        const cumsum = prev ? d.value + prev.cumsum : d.value
        d.cumsum = cumsum
        return d
      })
```

This code transforms the data into something like this:

```
    [
         {
            "key": 1,
            "values": 2,
            "cumsum": 2
         },
         {
            "key": 2,
            "values": 1,
            "cumsum": 3
         },
         {
            "key": 3,
            "values": 3,
            "cumsum": 6
         }
      ]
```

And now all you need to do is append the groups below your chart label

```
const svg = //your svg selector here

const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "group-labels")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", height + 30) //adjust this so that the group labels are below your labels

g.selectAll(".group-label")
    .data(groupedData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "group-label")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return xScale.bandwidth() * d.cumsum - xScale.bandwidth() * d.value / 2 })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "hanging")
```

Comment: Hi, Cathy! Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful. In my case I have scaleTime() on xAxis. Could you clarify what should I used instead of `xScale.bandwidth()`?

Comment: Even 2 years later, and this is extremely helpful. Thank you Cathy for your reply and ivan for creating this question.

Answer (score 0):

**1) add 'big attr to show the month name as the group**

```
 svg.call(axis)  .selectAll("text")
          .attr("class", (dt) => {
            if (isFirstWeekOfDate(dt)) return "big";
            return "small";
          });
```

**2) find .big then get parent node and add another 'text' init**

```
d3.selectAll(".big").each((d, i, ref) => {
  console.log(d, ref[i]);
  d3.select(ref[i].parentNode)
    .attr("class", "par")
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", "0em")
    .attr("y", -17)
    .attr("fill", "currentColor")
    .text(d.format("MMM"));
  return d;
});

  }
```