# Grouped category bar chart with different subcategories

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to draw a bar chart with different subcategories for every categories, an example of my dataframe is:

```
G1    A    74
      B    16
      C    56
      D    8


G2    E    63
      F    71
      G    78
      H    115
      I    645
```

I get stuck with all the solutions because my catecories have different subcategories, I would like to get something like this plot form this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812922/grouped-category-bar-chart-with-different-groups-in-d3) for javascript.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If subcategories are always different, i.e. could not exist elements `(A,a)` and `(B,a)`, you can use `seaborn` [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html?highlight=catplot#seaborn.catplot)

For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'cat2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'vals': np.random.random(5)
})
```

and plot with `cat2` (subcategory) at x-axis and `cat1` (main category) as hue with `dodge=False`

```
sns.catplot(
    kind='bar',
    data=df,
    x='cat2', y='vals',
    hue='cat1', dodge=False
)
```

that gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need python turtle or something like that to do draw it. But you can still use this:

```
G1[1] = A, 74
G1[2] = B, 16
#ect...
G2[1] = E, 63
```

and then for python turtle, try to use the letter's value and multiply it by something for it to have a bar. Other than these two tips, I am completely clueless :).